# Azure Powershell Script: Parse Error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, powershell-ise, azure-powershell

Trying to setup a new VM via PowerShell. Works fine when I copy & paste commands step by step to PowerShell ISE but, fails when I try to run them in one rush.

I have removed other parts of the script, it is also failing with only this lines:

```
$VM_NAME         = "VMNAME"
$VM_SIZE         = "Small"
$VM_IMAGE        = "5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-71-20150605"
$LOCATION        = "West Europe"
$STORAGE_ACCOUNT = "disktest"
$CLOUD_SERVICE   = "disktest"
$SSH_USER        = "azureuser"
$SSH_PASSWORD    = "324w##eANC"
$VIRTUAL_NETWORK = "Playground"
$SUBNET          = "P"

$BOOTSTRAP_CHEF      = $FALSE
$PATH_PUBLIC_CONFIG  = "publicconfig.json"
$PATH_PRIVATE_CONFIG = "privateconfig.json"
$DISK_CREATE         = $TRUE
$DISK_SIZE           = 500
$DISK_COUNT          = 2
$DISK_LABEL          = "datadisk"
$DISK_LUN            = 0
$REMOVE_SSH_ENDPOINT = $FALSE
$HTTP_ENDPOINT       = $FALSE
$SHUTDOWN            = $FALSE

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "SUB" -Current;

if (!(Test-AzureName -Storage $STORAGE_ACCOUNT)) {
    New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $STORAGE_ACCOUNT -Location $LOCATION
}

if (!(Test-AzureName -Service $CLOUD_SERVICE)) {
    New-AzureService -ServiceName $CLOUD_SERVICE -Location $LOCATION
}

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "SUB" -CurrentStorageAccountName $STORAGE_ACCOUNT

$existing = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $CLOUD_SERVICE -Name $VM_NAME
```

Error message:

```
In Zeile:36 Zeichen:1
+ $existing = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $CLOUD_SERVICE -Name $VM_NAME
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ausführbarer Skriptcode wurde im Signaturblock gefunden.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TokenAfterEndOfValidScriptText
```

If i first set the variables, remove them from script window, and run again it works like a charm.

Comment: Finding lots of references to this being a defect in PowerShell 3.0...  https://github.com/Microsoft/poshtools/issues/668

Comment: Based on similar errors, is your profile signed? What does  Get-ExecutionPolicy  return?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is "Solved" - after some hours talking to Microsoft: It is a bug in PowerShell 3.0 in combination with Windows 7!

To solve this, install PowerShell 4.0, Re-Install Azure PowerShell and reboot the workstation.